# Add custom properties to android build.gradle library project and override the same in the application project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like to add custom properties in my libraries build.gradle and allow the developers using my library to provide input to these properties from the applications build.gradle. How do I achieve this and how do I access these custom properties in my libraries build.gradle to perform certain actions.
For Eg:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        excludeModule "true"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        if(android.defaultConfig.excludeModule=="true"){
            println 'Including Feature A'
        }
    }
}
```

Now can the property **excludeModule "true"** be overridden in the applications using the build.gradle and can i use that variable to perform some build action in the library. How do i achieve this?